# How to get Spring Boot and OAuth2 example to use password grant credentials other than the default

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm following the basic Spring Boot OAuth2 example from Dave Syer: https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                // Just for laughs, apply OAuth protection to only 2 resources
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/","/admin/beans").and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId("sparklr");
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("sparklr")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
            .and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("sparklr")
                    .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value")
            .and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds("sparklr")
                    .secret("secret");
        // @formatter:on
        }

    }
}
```

The example works very well for both types of grants, but the password grant uses the Spring Boot default security user (the one that echo's out "Using default security password: 927ca0a0-634a-4671-bd1c-1323a866618a" during startup).

My question is how do you override the default user account and actually rely on a WebSecurityConfig?  I've added a section like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
protected static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder)
            throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user")
                .password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to override the default Spring user/password even though the documentation suggests that it should.

What am I missing to get this working?

Comment: No it shouldn't unless you add `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` to it.  You can set the default username/password in the application.properties file by setting the properties `security.user.name` and `security.user.password`. For more properties see the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: There's a better sample (more up to date) here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java#L81. That `authenticationManager` method is a new override in 2.0.4 snapshots (look at the implementation if you want to use it with 2.0.3).

Comment: @DaveSyer the sample didn't run for me, "Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration'"

Comment: Works for me and all tests are green (and your error fragment is too small to diagnose a problem). How are you building and running this application?

Answer (score 8):

As I'm still on 2.0.3, I tried a few more things and this appears to be working:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
protected static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin1").password("password1").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

By explicitly defining the authenticationManager bean, the built-in user authentication went away and it started relying on my own inMemoryAuthentication.  When 2.0.4 is released, I'll re-evaluate the solution that Dave posted above as it looks like it will be more elegant.

Comment: I think this solution is more suitable when you need to configure static pages within your OAuth Server and they need to be public. You can override `configure(HttpSecurity http)` and `configure(WebSecurity web)` and define specific `antMatchers` for that purpose.

Comment: Do you know how to store the users in a database and check their credentials at this point?

Answer (score 7):

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationManagerConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("min").password("min").roles("USER");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is much nicer solution than what I had to use in 2.0.3.